# call a group of compositing nodes and automatically connect them to the render layers

Tags: python, node-editor, compositing-nodes

because I have the need to constantly call the render node into my scenes. I would like to automate the process of joining variants with the same name. or somehow celebrate them

Ideally, of course, there would be an option to create up to 8 similar nodes with the necessary names. But my skills are not even enough to automatically connect one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will walk you through the process of joining one output to one input. You should be able to generalize from that.  For my example, I'm going to use a *Render Layers* node for the input side but instead of your group node I'm going to use a *Denoise* node for the output side.  I'm also going to assume that the nodes are already in the compositor node tree.

- The first thing you need to know is that the [*Compositor Node Tree*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNodeTree.html) is attached to the scene, so to access it use

  ```py
  tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
  ```
- You need to find the links for that tree

  ```py
  links = tree.links
  ```
- You need to find the *Render Layer* Node's *Image output*

  ```py
  render_node = tree.nodes['Render Layers']
  output_socket = render_node.outputs['Image']
  ```
- You need to find the *Denoise* Node's *Image input*

  ```py
  denoise_node = tree.nodes['Denoise']
  input_socket = denoise_node.inputs['Image']
  ```
- and you need to link them

  ```py
  links.new(output_socket, input_socket)
  ```

You'll need to repeat the last three steps for each pair of sockets you want to connect.

Putting the example altogether:

```py
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links
render_node = tree.nodes['Render Layers']
output_socket = render_node.outputs['Image']

denoise_node = tree.nodes['Denoise']
input_socket = denoise_node.inputs['Image']

links.new(output_socket, input_socket)
```

If the nodes aren't already created, you create them using `tree.nodes.new()`:

```py
render_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')
denoise_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeDenoise')
```

To access your group node, you refer to it by its name, ie `tree.nodes['Group']`.

To add a group takes two steps, creating the *Node Group* node, and linking it to an existing node tree:

```
group_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
group_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup']
```

where you replace `'NodeGroup'` with the name of your node group.

Creating the Node Tree node group is outside of the scope of the question.

Finally, since the names of the *Render Layers* node's outputs don't seem to directly match the names of your group's inputs; I suggest you use some sort of data structure, such as a list of tuples to store the names for you to iterate over to create all of the connections.  Here's one approach:

```py
def attach_sockets(tree, from_node, to_node, socket_list):
    ''' socket_list is alist of tuples of socket names.
        The first is the output socket of from_node to use.
        The second is the input socket of to_node.
        Each pair is linked.
        No error handling is done.
    '''
    for sockets in socket_list:
        src = from_node.outputs[sockets[0]]
        dst = to_node.inputs[sockets[1]]
        tree.links.new(src, dst)

# A list of tuples containing the names of the output socket
# and input socket for a set of attachments.
socket_list = [
    ('Image', 'Image'),
    ('Denoising Normal', 'Normal'),
    ('Denoising Albedo', 'Albedo'),
]

attach_sockets(tree, render_node, group_node, socket_list)
```

Comment: KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Render Layers" not found. He writes this when trying to refer to the line render_node = tree.nodes['Render Layers']